# if-statement executing when it shouldn't (kind of)

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

```
int trees = 3;
int tree_x, tree_y;
for(int r = 0; r < m_townsize; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < m_townsize; c++)
  {
    if(r == 0 || c == 0 || r == (m_townsize - 1) || c == (m_townsize - 1))
      m_town[r][c] = 'W';
    while(trees > 0)
    {
      tree_x = random() % m_townsize;
      tree_y = random() % m_townsize;
      cout << tree_y << "," << tree_x << endl;
      if(m_town[tree_y][tree_x] == ' ')
      {
        m_town[tree_y][tree_x] = 'T';
        trees -= 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According the code I have written, if there is a space character at the coordinate of the tree, it should place a tree and lower the tree count by 1.

If there is not a space there, it should skip placing a tree, thus not decrementing. This *should* cause it to pick another set of coordinates and run through again.

However, if you look at this particular output it is running to the if-statement skipping the first option to replace it with a T--since it is a W--but still decrementing by 1. I don't get it. It should skip the statement all together, not skip just the first line. Netbeans tells me my brackets are right, so it shouldn't be an issue with the assignment belonging to the if and the decrement belonging to the while.

If I make a do-while loop it places a whole bunch. I don't know what's happening.

[image]

This output placed 2 trees.

Comment: Copy-paste the _relevant_ piece of code as _text_, not as an image. Preferably, a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for including the code as text. Are you sure the `while` loop should be _inside_ those `for` loops? Your trees get overwritten by `W`s if it is on the border. I think you need to move the `while` loop outside those `for` loops.

Comment: I will put it outside and see what happens. I put it there because I wanted it to occur right after placing the walls. That is what the W's are.

Comment: You really really want to draw the border _first_, and only _afterwards_ place the trees. As written, the tree-placing `while` loop runs only once when only the upper-left `W` has been placed. (When the rest of the `W`s are placed the variable `trees` is already zero.)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks guys! I guess I didn't realize it DID place the trees and wrote the Ws over them.

Comment: You could also have avoided generating random coordinates on the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are walking over each coordinate.

If it is on the edge you put a `'W'`.  Then you randomly place a tree `'T'`.

Then you proceed to the next coordinate.

This means you can place some trees in squares before you overwrite with a `'W'`.

Finish *all* the walls before placing trees.  Consider a more efficient way to place walls to, like doing each edge instead of loopimg over the middle abd doing nothing.

Comment: I hadn't realized I was placing the T's first. I do plan on making it more efficient later. I just want to get the beginnings of it started to have it workable and refine it as I go.